# Создать бд с помощью JSON

Tags: mysql, json

Всем привет, есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(35) not null,
`price` decimal(15, 2) not null,
`category` JSON,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES(
    null,
    "Двигатель",
    '{"Категория": ["Самолёт", "Автомобиль", "Вертолёт"]}',
    150
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES(
    null,
    "Инструменты",
    '{"Категория": ["Для приготовления пищи", "Для самолетостроения", "Для судностроения"]}',
    150
);
```

Но как правильно делать insert запрос, надо добавить товар к категории, с ценой?
Я совсем запутался с этим синтаксисом, а на вид - легко.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO products(name, price, category) VALUES(
    "Инструменты",
    '{"Категория": ["Для приготовления пищи", "Для самолетостроения", "Для судностроения"]}',
    150
);
```

Comment: но ведь цена 150 для всех трех категорий .или как?

Comment: у вас категории в строке JSON. Получается так, да. Иначе непонятна задача, формулируйте по-другому